Preserving Operation Names and Input Requests in Apache CXF 4.0.0 Code Generation
When you make Java code from a WSDL using Apache CXF's cxf-codegen-plugin version 4.0.0, it usually makes the operation name and adds "Request" or "Response" to create the input and output request objects. But, I need to keep the operation name and input request object with the same name.
Request for Help:
Can we do this in Apache CXF 4.0.0? It used to work fine in version 3.6, but now, since I'm moving to Spring Boot 3.2, I have to use CXF 4.0.0. I'm looking for a way to keep the operation name and input request object name same because I can't change the wsdl contract.

Could you share some sample code to explain what changed between your code generation from 3.x to 4.x CXF ?
